# PHP Curl (Or something like it) only retrieve rendered results not all the HTML tags

Tags: php, curl

I have been searching for a way to pull in all the words a person sees on a web page with PHP. I know I can use curl or filegetcontents, but that returns all the HTML, I just want the rendered text (not the formatting of it or images or anything else). Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you talking about scraping? It's been a few years, but I accomplished this with cURL and parsing the response with some built in PHP DOM parser. This one looks easy enough to use: https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well curl is not a html processor. Lynx is a html processor  You can use `lynx -dump Https://stackoverflow.com`

> dumps the formatted output of the default document or those specified on the command line to standard output. Unlike interactive mode, all documents are processed.

[Lynx manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lynx)

You can run Linux/Windows commands in php with proc_open() function, link to manual:
[php proc_open](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php)